# need to count the values in an single field

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL query is

```
SELECT *
  FROM fchost.iv_stock_details
 WHERE cod_stock = '16' AND cod_stock_branch = '1134'
```

it will return result with many columns but my concern is with one particular column i.e. stock status it will have values as `UUUUIIII` totally 200 numbers will be there

I need to count the number of I and U

For example

> UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIIUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUUIIIIIIII

In the stock status column the result will be like this, I need to count this values separately and display

For example if 'U' is 180 I want  to display the place value from 1 to 200 of it
also if 'I' is 20 need the place value  and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [the `regexp_count()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_COUNT.html), with a very simple pattern consisting of the character you are looking for:

```
SELECT regexp_count(stock_status, 'U') as u_count,
       regexp_count(stock_status, 'I') as i_count
  FROM fchost.iv_stock_details
 WHERE cod_stock = '16' AND cod_stock_branch = '1134';

   U_COUNT    I_COUNT
---------- ----------
       180         20
```

Comment: Thank you , but i need the face value of the counts for example starting from 1 to 200 which place is the I value and U value

Comment: That isn't what your question says at all. Edit your question to explain what you are really trying to do, and include the expected output.